# Animated transitions using morenavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

Using Swift 4.2 I have a custom `UITabBarController` with 12 items. I never actually show the TabBar but handle transitions with buttons that set the `.selectedIndex`. I have a delegate that implements

```
tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom
        fromViewController: UIViewController, to toViewController: UIViewController)
```

which give me a transitioning object for animating transitions among the first 4 of the 12 items. But because the other 8 items are implicitly handled by the 'more' controller, this function is not called when transitioning among these items so I don't know how to assign animations for these transitions.

Is there a way to call this function *or some substitute* for these animating these transitions? One suggestion I see is to replace the TabBar with UIPage views, but my TabBar items are each `UINavigationController`s, so I don't think this would work for me.

Comment: You should implement your own container view controller and perform any needed animations when adding child view controllers. You can read about container view controllers [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: Thanks, I’ve now done this, but I can’t figure out the animations. By analogy to push I’d like to use the delegate of the NavigationController where I have defined lots of custom animations, but they depend on a transitionContext and I don’t see how to set this — it happens automatically for push. Somehow I should use transition(from: to: animations: completion:), but where and with what delegations?

Comment: What does your animation controller look like?